# Change account on GEE plugin

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine

I used Gee plugin for QGIS with my personal e-mail, but now I need use my the professional e-mail on GEE plugin for access assets of my work. How can I change the account on Gee plugin?

Comment: I suggest you create a new account with your company email.